# Aspnet Core MVC Validation messages always visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-core

I'm implementing form validation, my model looks like this:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
}
```

my view looks like this:

```
<form asp-action="SaveProfile" asp-controller="User" asp- profile="@Model" asp-file="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label asp-for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="firstname" asp-for="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
    <span asp-validation-for="Firstname"></span>
    <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

My controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Profile profile)
{   
    return View(await _userRepository.ReadProfile(User.Identity.Name));
}
```

and `ReadProfile()`:

```
public async Task<Profile> ReadProfile(string user)
{
    var profile = await _context.User
                    .Where(u => u.Email == user)
                    .Include(s => s.Schedule)
                    .Include(s => s.Skills)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync() ?? await CreateProfile(user);
    var schedule = profile.Schedule.OrderBy(sd => sd.StartDate).ToList();
    profile.Schedule = schedule;

    return profile;

}
```

When I load the view I see `Firstname is required` even if the field contains data on submission

any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a separate project - just out of the box project with Model and View from your post?

Comment: Are you getting the message when you load your page (GET action) or when you submit your form

Comment: @Shyju both on load and submit

Comment: That could only happen if you have added a `ModelState` error. Most likely because your GET method includes a parameter for your model (show the relevant code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i've added `index` from my controller and the method it calls for your reference

Comment: Remove the `Profile profile` parameter from your `Index` method (the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes that model, sets its properties from the request - in your case you did not call it using `../Index?Firstname=someValue` - and because you have a required property a `ModelState` error is added)